# How can I get the single val from a SQL Server CE query that returns one column from one row?

Tags: dataset, sql-server-ce, row, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I need to retrieve the val from one column of a table, any record (the val should be the same at any given time in all records; that is to say, if it's "3", it will be "3" in all of them; if it's "17", it will be "17" in all of them (or "42" or whatever)).

So I saw legacy code like this:

```
DataSet ds = dbconn.getDataSet("SELECT siteNo FROM workTables");

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    siteNum = row["siteNo"].ToString();
}
```

...which works, but seems kludgy and wasteful, as a gazillion records could be looped through, and only the value of the last loop is used.

So I tried to "cut to the chase" with this code:

```
String siteNum = ds.Tables[0].Rows.ToString();
```

...but got an exception because siteNum is `System.Data.DataRowCollection`

I then tried this:

```
String siteNum = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
```

...but got an exception because siteNum is `System.Data.DataRow`

So I finally reverted to the legacy kludgy code, pretty much, modifying it like so:

```
DataSet ds = dbconn.getDataSet("SELECT siteNo FROM workTables");

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    siteNum = row["siteNo"].ToString();
    // just need the first one
    break;
}
```

This works, but I'm sure it's not "the preferred method." Who knows a "more better" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExecuteScalar` to return the first column of the first row in a result set:

```
var result = connection.ExecuteScalar("SELECT siteNo FROM workTables");
if((result != null) && (result != DBNull.Value))
{
    site = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

Comment: Probably worth at least experimenting to see if a TableDirect call is even faster, since it would avoid the query processor altogether.  It would depend on the amount of data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to SELECT TOP 1 siteNo FROM workTables
This way you minimize processing on the server and network traffic.

Comment: I'll try it, but I'm not sure that's supported in SQL CE.

Comment: I haven't used SQL Server CE but I would imagine it's supported. If it's not then you could change TOP 1 to Max(siteNo), maybe the max function is supported?  The right way to do it would be to have a stored procedure with one output parameter, are stored procs supported?  If you must retrieve all the data and only get the first row just do it this way: string sitenum = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["siteNo"].ToString();

Comment: No, no SPs; I don't think Max is supported, either. It's a very stripped-down subset of SQL; it should be called the Kardashian edition or something like that.

Comment: Hopefully TOP 1 is supported.  If it isn't you can just get the value from the first row like I showed before: string sitenum = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["siteNo"].ToString();

Comment: I like your "ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["siteNo"].ToString();" better than "Top 1"; that works.